# Put validation messages into database

Tags: java, customization, bean-validation

I want to put validation messages used by Bean Validation (JSR 303) ex.:

```
javax.validation.constraints.AssertFalse.message=must be false
javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue.message=must be true ...
```

into a database so that when an administrator adds a new language he can adds the translations for that language.

I know how to access a resource bundle mapped from a database but I can't figure out how to extend/customize the bean validation classes so they can access the validation messages from a database...

Is it possible to obtain what I want ?

Many thanks in advance for driving me into the right direction.

HERE THE SOLUTION (I don't know if this is the best solution but it works...):

As suggested by @gastaldi I've created an implementation on MessageInterpolator interface:

```
package giates.validation;

import com.infomaxgroup.adaecommerce.bundles.DatabaseResourceBundle;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.validation.MessageInterpolator;

public class LocaleMessageInterpolator implements MessageInterpolator {
  protected final String BRACE_OPEN = "\\{";
  protected final String BRACE_CLOSE = "\\}";

  @Override
  public String interpolate(String message, Context context) {
    return interpolate(message, context, Locale.ITALIAN);
  }

  @Override
  public String interpolate(String message, Context context, Locale locale) {
    DatabaseResourceBundle bundle = new DatabaseResourceBundle(locale);
    String messageKey = context.getConstraintDescriptor().getAttributes().get("message").toString();
    message = bundle.getString(messageKey.replaceAll(BRACE_OPEN, "").replaceAll(BRACE_CLOSE, ""));
    Map<String, Object> attributes = context.getConstraintDescriptor().getAttributes();
    for (String key : attributes.keySet()) {
      String value = attributes.get(key).toString();
      key = BRACE_OPEN + key + BRACE_CLOSE;
      message = message.replaceAll(key, value);
    }
    return message;
  }
}
```

then I've created META-INF/validation.xml and added the customized messageinterpolator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<validation-config
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration">
    <message-interpolator>giates.validation.LocaleMessageInterpolator</message-interpolator>
</validation-config>
```

as soon as I post a model with failed validations the interpolator calls DatabaseResourceBundle and creates the resulting message...

All works great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a customized MessageInterpolator for that and configure in your validator.xml

Comment: And probably a ResourceBundle specialization as well

Comment: And this: http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com.br/2010_06_01_archive.html

Comment: Many thanks @gastaldi, you drive me into the right direction, I've customized the messageinterpolator and read the messages from the database, I put the solution into my question...