# Hibernate Validator custom MessageInterpolator and Primefaces client side validation

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces, validation, bean-validation

I want to load my validation messages from database, so I defined a custom MessageInterpolator and set up validation.xml to use it, similar to the post [Put validation messages into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035032/put-validation-messages-into-database).

All works well if I use server side validation, interpolate() gets called and I can substitute the message. However, Primefaces client side validation simply takes the non-interpolated value from the annotation definition and uses it as the error message. It doesn't call the interpolate() message at any point.

I'd really like to use client side validation, so I'm wondering if there is a way to make Primefaces ClientSideValidation generator interpolate the message in the same manner that custom MessageInterpolator does. Do Primefaces perform an interpolation of their own somehow?

Thanks

Comment: This looks much like a bug in PF. I'd rather report it at their issue tracker.

Comment: I've the same problem converting an application from JEE6 to JEE7 (using PF 5.0 under Glassfish 4.1) no call to messageinterpolator...

Comment: Same problem with primefaces 5.1...